# Getting optimal vocab size and embedding dimensionality using GridSearchCV

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, hyperparameters

I'm trying to use `GridSearchCV` to find the best hyperparameters for an LSTM model, including the best parameters for vocab size and the word embeddings dimension. First, I prepared my testing and training data.

```
x = df['tweet_text']
y = df['potentially_harmful']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size= 0.2, random_state=0)

x_train= x_train.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
y_train= y_train.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
x_test = x_test.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = y_test.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)
```

And then I tried to create a model that I could use for my `GridSearchCV`. I know to use a Keras model for the grid search, you need to use `KerasClassifier` or `KerasRegressor`. I also make sure to adapt `x`, not `x_train` or anything, as `x` is the full `x_data` and I assume it needs to vectorize all of `x` so that all input docs have a consistent vectorized form.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier, KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

def build_model(max_tokens, max_len, dropout):
    
    model = Sequential()
    vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(

    max_tokens=max_tokens,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=max_len,
    )
    vectorize_layer.adapt(x)
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))
    model.add(vectorize_layer)
    model.add(Embedding(max_tokens + 1, 128))
    model.add(LSTM(64, dropout = dropout, recurrent_dropout = dropout))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
    model.compile(
    optimizer='adam', 
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
    )
    return model
```

Here I try to instantiate the model with the params. The classifier complained that I should add the `dropout = 0.2, max_len = 5, max_tokens=25` part.

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model, dropout = 0.2, max_len = 5, max_tokens=25)
params = {
    "max_tokens" : [25, 50, 500, 5000],
    "max_len" : [5, 50, 500, 1000],
    "dropout" : [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
}

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, scoring = 'accuracy', param_grid = params,  cv = 3, verbose = 2, error_score = 'raise')

grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Then, I get this error:

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 80 candidates, totalling 240 fits
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'promo looks promising pls say absence means fauxfoodies r couple eliminated next round ugh cantstandthem mkr'
```

Which confuses me. This model works if I just try to instantiate a model with something like `model = build_model(...)` and try `model.fit(x_train, y_train)`, for example, and it doesn't have trouble converting strings to floats then. Why is it unable to do so now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with scikeras but I got errors because it doesn't accept [not-numerical inputs](https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras/blob/cbc7940df9b77e69f1bf3f2735fc980849cfd4a7/scikeras/wrappers.py#L630) (in our case the input is in *str* format). So I came back to the standard [keras wrapper](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/KerasClassifier).

The focal point here is that the model is not built correctly. The `TextVectorization` must be put inside the `Sequential` model like shown in the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization#example_3).

So the `build_model` function becomes:

```
def build_model(max_tokens, max_len, dropout):

    vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=max_tokens,
        output_mode="int",
        output_sequence_length=max_len,
    )
    vectorize_layer.adapt(X)
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))   ## <=== enable str inputs
    model.add(vectorize_layer)    ## <==== add TextVectorization inside Sequential
    model.add(Embedding(max_tokens + 1, 128))
    model.add(LSTM(64, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=dropout))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

I made a dummy experiment with a binary version of `fetch_20newsgroups` and it works.

```
# IMPORT USEFUL LIBRARIES
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

# READ THE DATA
categories = ["rec.sport.baseball", "talk.politics.misc"]
X, y = fetch_20newsgroups(categories=categories, return_X_y=True)
X = np.asarray(X).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.asarray(y).reshape(-1,1)

# HYPERPARAMETER SEARCHING
param_grid = {
    "max_tokens" : [25, 50],
    "max_len" : [5, 50],
    "dropout" : [0.1, 0.2],
}
model = GridSearchCV(KerasClassifier(build_model), param_grid, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=3, batch_size=512, verbose=2)
```